# How to say in tex "missing T = 0" (that would mean there was no such T == 0)?

Tags: equations

I think about trying `$T=0$` but it seems kind of wrong because we do not assign but check for value `==` to... So what is the correct way to say that somewhere there was no such variable (say named T) that would be equal to some value (say 0)?

Comment: TeX is just a typesetter not an arbiter of notation in different fields. You appear to be talking about assignment in a programming language, each language has its own vocabulary and notation for assignment and missing values. TeX is flexible enough to typeset any such convention, but you need to say what you want, then someone can say how to do that in TeX.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an construct to first check if the variable is defined, and then check to see if it has the appropriate value. Here I have used [the `xstring` package's](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) `\IfEq` for the numerical comparison but any other method will do:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\CheckValue}[1]{%
    \ifdefined\T%
        \IfEq{\T}{0}{%
           Variable T is defined and is zero%
        }{%
           Variable T is defined and is not zero%
        }%
    \else%
       Variable T not defined%
    \fi%
}%

\begin{document}
\CheckValue{\T}

\newcommand{\T}{1}
\CheckValue{\T}

\renewcommand{\T}{0}
\CheckValue{\T}
\end{document}
```

---

Without using the `xstring` package you can (thanks to @egreg):

1. Use `\pdfstrcmp` which will check that the macro `\T` expands to zero, but not if `\T` is a counter

   ```
   \newcommand{\CheckValue}[1]{%
       \ifdefined\T%
           \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\T}{0}=0\relax%
               Variable T is defined and is zero%
           \else%
               Variable T is defined and is not zero%
           \fi%
       \else%
           Variable T not defined%
       \fi%
   }%
   ```
2. If you're sure that `\T` is a counter or a macro expanding to a number, then `\ifnum\T=0` is sufficient:

   ```
   \newcommand{\CheckValue}[1]{%
       \ifdefined\T%
           \ifnum\T=0\relax%
               Variable T is defined and is zero%
           \else%
               Variable T is defined and is not zero%
           \fi%
       \else%
           Variable T not defined%
       \fi%
   }%
   ```